# Average # of trials to achieve success across multiple variables with different probabilities.

Tags: probability

Imagine you are rolling multiple sided dice. You start by rolling let's say 4 dice at a time with side numbers 6,7,8, and 9. What is the average number of attempts until all 4 dice have rolled a 1? (Upon success the die is removed). I've taken a basic high school stats course but I'm a little fuzzy on that and couldn't think of how to do this. (This is not what I want to calculate but I would prefer a general example being solved rather than bombard you with the specific variables actually at play)

Comment: You could look at the distribution of the maximum.  Or you could work from states (where a state records which of the dice have shown a $1$ so far).

Comment: Should say:  as the number of variables grows, and the rules grow more intricate, it might become easier to simply simulate the process and estimate things that way.

Comment: What do you mean by "side numbers $6$,$7$,$8$, and $9$?" To me this would seem a die could not roll a $1$...